# How to regenerate grpc classes in dotnet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I was checking the official Microsoft docs regarding the usage of grpc services. I have downloaded their famous greeter service example and ran It successfully but the docs didn't explain how to regenerate the grpc classes after the proto files have been edited.

Is there a command I can use for this purpose? (Let's say I have added a new rpc method in my proto service definition, now how can make dotnet refresh the generated server code?)

Dotnet version I am using: v6
Edit: I prefer to use vs code and not vs, I mostly run dotnet commands through cli.

## Details

I ran `dotnet new grpc` command from my command prompt in order to generate a grpc template. It had a `greet.proto` file in it by default. I edited it and added another rpc method to the `Greeter` service

### greet.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Auth";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
  rpc Test(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (HelloReply); // +++ I've added this here
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

But when I want to implement the `Test` method in the generated service file, I see the following error: `C:\Users\masoum\source\progs\questify-community\questify-microservices\Auth\Services\GreeterService.cs (22,38): error CS0115: 'GreeterService.Test()': no suitable method`

Comment: What command did you run? What happens if you run it again?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have added the details in my last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information I guess that you modified the proto but didn't generate the service stub. After changing `greet.proto` you should compile (`dotnet build`) to get the service and client stubs generated with the new method and then you can implement them. Also, you shouldn't change the proto compiler generated service file these are meant to be implemented, not modified.

Comment: Oh thanks, after building the project the problem got removed.